# Loop through a multi dimensional array checking a specific key for repeat values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array that I have got from a database and I want to check this array for duplicate data and store it in another array of duplicates. my code is as follows

```
    //create temp array
    $tmp = array();

    foreach ($matchingarray as $nameKey => $match) {
          // loop through and stoe the contents of that array to another so i can compare
          $tmp[] = $match;
    }
     // create an array to store duplicates
    $duplicatesArray = array();
    // if the temp array is not empty then loop through both arrays 
    if (! empty($tmp)) {
        foreach ($tmp as $key => $tmpvalue) {
            foreach ($matchingarray as $key => $match) {
               // if a key name is the same in both arrays then add it tothe duplicates array
               if ($tmpvalue['name'] == $match['name']) {
                   $duplicatesArray = $match;
                   }
                }
            }
        }
       //count how many are duplicates
       $dups = count($duplicatesArray);
```

What I would like to know is this the right logic?

Comment: why not count the duplicates with mysql?

Comment: thanks for your input it was a practice in using php as i am making my way from java to php and im a bit lost at times in regards to functions and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I will take where Igoel left off

there is 1 error and also 1 suggest that i will make.

**Error**:
you cannot reuse $key twice in the foreach because they will override.

**Suggestion** as what Igoel stated: your best bet for duplicate effectively is to use sql. SQL is faster at processing than looping through arrays. Don't forget you need to load the data into memory and thats costly.

Comment: very true! it was an exercise of php rather than anything else, im trying to learn the code a bit better. thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
<?php
static $cnt = array();
$min = 1;
$coll = array(
    'dep1' => array(
        'fy' => array('john', 'johnny', 'victor'),
        'sy' => array('david', 'arthur'),
        'ty' => array('sam', 'joe', 'victor')
    ),
    'dep2' => array(
        'fy' => array('natalie', 'linda', 'molly'),
        'sy' => array('katie', 'helen', 'sam', 'ravi', 'vipul'),
        'ty' => array('sharon', 'julia', 'maddy')
    )
);

function recursive_search(&$v, $k){
    global $cnt;
    $cnt[] = $v;
}
array_walk_recursive($coll, 'recursive_search');

$newNumbers = array_filter(
    array_count_values($cnt),
    function ($value) use($min) {
        return ($value > $min);
    }
);
echo "Values > 1 are repeated \n";
print_r(array_count_values($cnt));
echo "Values repeted\n";
print_r($newNumbers);
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://eval.in/122567)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ill will test this out and let you know.